# Crash reporting in Library module

Tags: android, crash, crash-reports

I have already tried crashlytics but it is not supported.

this is the reply i got from their team

*Thanks for reaching out on this and Crashlytics, or any part of Fabric, cannot be included in any SDK that is distributed to external apps. As you mentioned, this will cause conflicts for both the SDK and app. With that said, we do hope to support this in the future and if you'd like, I can keep you updated on that.*

I have tried to set my own UncaughtExceptionHandler for this but the problem with that is my library also starts to catch error of the client's application module.

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Comment: Did you find any solution/workaround of your asked question?