# How do I obtain package specific crash report/data only for my library module/package (implemented in some Application via gradle dependency)

Tags: android, android-library, crash-reports

I have implemented a library module and publish the library. Developer can incoporate it via gradle dependency I have given to him.

My Question is when I somehow configured crash reporting (via third party library) by obtaining the `Application` class's instance in my library, I will also have the crash reports of that android client application.

*I just want to have crash reports only for my library's module/package.*

> I have searched it on Google and found a similar [Duplicate
>   Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47796058/crash-reporting-in-library-module) already asked but **un-answered** yet. Thats why I am
>   asking it again.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any library that could help you. A possible solution would be for you to have a global exception handler (like the one explained [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-global-exception-handler)) in your library which sends the exceptions using retrofit / okhttp / whatever you prefer to an api/service you set up.